# TextBox.Text binding to a ViewModel's property

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, properties, textbox

I have a problem with two way binding a TextBox content to a property in another class. Searching stackoverflow gave a lot of tips/solutions but none seem to work.

In my XAML code I have:

```
< TextBox ... Width="336" IsReadOnly="True"
 Text="{Binding Path=AssignedClearProgram, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

(... I removed all non important items)

In the accompanies cs code I have:

```
public CombiWindow(Combi combi)
{
    ViewModel = new CombiViewModel(combi);
    DataContext = ViewModel;
}
```

In the CombiViewModel:

```
    [UsedImplicitly]
    public string AssignedClearProgram { get; set; }
```

It seems that the first time I assign AssignedClearProgram, the textbox is filled with the text that I set, however after the window is displayed and AssignedClearProgram gets updated from the code (i.e. the set method is called), the data is not updated in the screen.

Does anybody have a solution to update the textbox when this variable is changed?

Kind regards,

Michel

Comment: Why is the binding mode twoway?  I would have thought there was no input from the view....

Comment: Probably one way binding would be ok too (but would not matter for the answering of the question).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your viewmodel class needs to implement INotifyPropertyChanged and you need to raise that interface's event whenever you change the property. Then the binding will spot changes and update the textbox.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to tell that I already was using INotifyPropertyChanged but I forgot to add the OnPropertyChanged call in the set method. Thank you very much!

Comment: Best bet is to put in in the property setter and check that the value actually changed before raising the event.

Answer (score 2):

Your view model class should implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

Your property would then look like the following:

```
private string assignedClearProgram;

public string AssignedClearProgram
{
   get { return assignedClearProgram; }
   set
   {
       if (assignedClearProgram != value)
       {
           assignedClearProgram = value;

           // Notify property has changed here using PropertyChanged event from INotifyPropertyChanged.
       }
   }
}
```

Read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged.aspx) article for an example of how to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and utilize its `PropertyChanged` event.

Comment: Thanks however I really got it to work; btw, I really need to call the OnPropertyChanged event explicitly (don't know if you meant that here instead of the // Notify ... line. However +1 for the link.

Comment: Yes, I did, I just didn't know how you would have implemented it and thus left the comment.